# TypeError: Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined (mariaDB, ExpressJs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mariadb, sequelize.js

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined

`findAll` function makes error, but `Connection` was successful.
And database is also created under the name `managers`.

---

- app.js
- models

  - index.js
  - maria

    - manager.model.js
- bin

  - www.js

**models/index.js**

```js
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

const manager = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'mariadb',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: '13306',
    username: 'xxx',
    password: 'xxx',
    database: 'test',
    timezone: 'Asia/Seoul'
});

require('./maria/manager.model')(manager);

module.exports=manager;
```

**models/maria/manager.model.js**

```js
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize) => {
     sequelize.define('manager', {
        id: {
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        name: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        }
    }, {timestamps: true }).sync({force:false});
};
```

**app.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const db = require('./models');
console.log(`Checking database connection...`);

// It works!
db.authenticate().then(()=>{
  console.log('Database connection OK!');
});

// It makes error!
const find_test = db.manager.findAll();
console.log(find_test);
```

Comment: As the error states, `db.manager` is undefined

Comment: Your `models/index.js` exports `manager`, not an object with a `manager` property. Where you have `const db = require('./models')`, `db` is already `manager`

Comment: @Phill


`const find_test = db.findAll();`

It makes same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- app.js
- sequelize

  - models

    - manager.model.js
  - index.js

**app.js**

```
const maria = require('./sequelize');
const { models } = require('./sequelize');

console.log(`Checking database connection...`);
maria.authenticate()
    .then(()=>{
      console.log('Database connection OK!');
    });

const test = models.manager.findOne()
```

**sequelize/index.js**

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

const maria = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'mariadb',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: '13306',
    username: 'xxxx',
    password: 'xxxx',
    database: 'test',
    timezone: 'Asia/Seoul'
});

require('./models/manager.model')(maria)

module.exports=maria;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all what is containing your `manager` variable ?
your `manager` variable is containing the connection sequelize. Your objectif is to request your table `manager` but you can't to this with the variable. Because he doesn't contain table specification but database connection.

```
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize) => {
     return sequelize.define('manager', {
        id: {
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        name: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        }
    }, {timestamps: true });
};
```

In this file, you need to return the definition of your table.

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

const manager = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'mariadb',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: '13306',
    username: 'xxx',
    password: 'xxx',
    database: 'test',
    timezone: 'Asia/Seoul'
});

const myTable = require('./maria/manager.model')(manager);

module.exports= {
  manager, myTable
};
```

and in this file, you need to store the return value in a variable.and export it.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const { manager, myTable }= require('./models');
console.log(`Checking database connection...`);

// It works!
manager.authenticate().then(()=>{
  console.log('Database connection OK!');
});


const find_test = myTable.findAll();
console.log(find_test);
```

Finaly in the next file, import the new exported variables ! and Enjoy !